# Accessing the first node of stl list

Tags: c++, recursion, stl

I am trying to assign the first node of the stl list to a binary tree node...
The problem I am faced with is that I do not see a tool in the stl listed functions to allow me to do that.

For example:
If I create the following list:

```
list<int> L;
L.push_front(10);
L.push_back(20);
L.push_back(30);
L.push_back(40);
L.push_back(50);
L.push_back(60);
L.push_back(70);
```

The list should be: 10,20,30,40,50,60,70...

My question is, is there a way to assign a new node (in particular I am using binary tree node) to the first node of the list. I need the node value not the integer value, to pass into a function that converts the list to a binary tree.

This did not work for obvious reasons:

```
binary_tree_node<Item> *node = list.front();
```

as it is attempting to assign an integer to a node value, but I was just curious if there is a way to assign that first node to a new node.

This is the function which I am trying to use

```
template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> &list, int start, int end)
{
binary_tree_node<Item> *node = list.front();
if (start > end) return NULL;
int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
binary_tree_node<Item>* leftChild = convert(list, start, mid-1);
binary_tree_node<Item>* parent = new binary_tree_node<Item> (node->data());
parent->left() = leftChild;
node = node->next();
parent->right() = convert(list, mid+1, end);
return parent;
}

template <class Item> 
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> &head, int n) 
{
return convert(head, 0, n-1);
}
```

Comment: What is `binary_tree_node` ? your custom class ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  create a binary tree?  Use `std::list` in your binary tree node?  Use `std::list` to contain the nodes?

Comment: its a custom template class implementation written by the author of the textbook used for this course. @Jarod42

Comment: The overall goal of the assignment is to take stl list and convert it to a binary search tree using a recursive function @Thomas Matthews

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you make a constructor in your class `binary_tree_node<T>`, something like this ::

```
class binary_tree_node<T> {
    T classMember;

    binary_tree_node(T &data) {
        classMember = data;
    }
}
```

So, now when you are taking `Item` values stored in the `list` for building a node, you can do something like this ::

```
binary_tree_node<Item> *node = new binary_tree_node(list.front());
```

Moreover, `list.front()` only gives you the first element in the list, I think you would like to remove it before going into the next recursion, so make sure you call `list.pop_front()` when the first element in the list is of no use!